# Why is base64encoded output different for the same image?

Tags: python, opencv, base64

This function below reads an image and converts it into base64 image string

```
def getBase64Image(filePath):
    with open(filePath, "rb") as img_file:
        my_string = base64.b64encode(img_file.read())
        my_string = my_string.decode('utf-8')
    return my_string
```

However, the function below take image as array(loaded from OpenCV) and converts it into base64 image string

```
def convertToBase64(image):
    image.tobytes()
    my_string = base64.b64encode(image)
    my_string = my_string.decode('utf-8')
    return my_string
```

The output string from the first function differs from the string produced by the second function. Why is that?

Ideally, I want the second function to produce the same base64 string as the first function.

Please, can someone guide me on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first function uses the PNG/JPG image data "as-is" and encodes it.

Your second function uses RAW bytes from the RGB or grayscale representation of the image and encodes that. If you want to convert RAW RGB to an image, you may use `cv2.imencode()` which will ouput PNG or JPG or whatever you like.

```
def convertToBase64(image):
    #image.tobytes() -- don't need this
    _, converted = cv2.imencode( '.png', image)  # here the magic happens
    my_string = base64.b64encode(converted)  # and here
    my_string = my_string.decode('utf-8')
    return my_string
```

And yeah, just in case it's not clear. You DON'T have to save the encoded image anywhere, it's all happening in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You are encoding fundamentally different structures.  The first method is reading in the bytes of a compressed image format such as jpeg or png.  Even if it is a bitmap image, there is a lot of extra data stored in the image that is not in the raw array data.

The second method is taking an `h` x `w` x `3` array of the pixel data, converting it to a byte string, and then 64bit encoding it.  You can see the difference by comparing the byte strings of black and white data array compared to the saved bitmap image.

Comment: So does that mean, the only option I have is to save the image and read it back? I am processing a video frame by frame. Saving the frame and loading back up will just seem to increase the latency and reduce output fps

Comment: Save it to a `io.BytesIO` object and then `read()` back the data.